# R crashes when trying to use the seewave library ("can't find usable tk.tcl")

Tags: r, scripting

I want to write a simple R script using the `seewave` library.

When I call this from the normal R GUI, I get:

```
> library(seewave)
Loading Tcl/Tk interface ...
```

It seemingly works, but whenever I try to run a command from this package, it crashes. In the following screenshot, I was trying to run `readWave` and upon pressing `(`, the following happened:

[image]

Similarly, when I try to run a simple Rscript like this …

```
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript
library(seewave)
```

I get the error:

```
Warning message:
In fun(...) : Can't find a usable tk.tcl in the following directories: 
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Versions/8.5/Resources/Scripts/tk8.5 /System/Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Versions/8.5/Resources/Scripts/tk8.5/Resources/Scripts /System/Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Versions/8.5/Resources/tk8.5 /System/Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Versions/8.5/Resources/tk8.5/Resources/Scripts ./lib/tk8.5 ./lib/tk8.5/Resources/Scripts ~/Library/Tcl/tk8.5 ~/Library/Tcl/tk8.5/Resources/Scripts /Library/Tcl/tk8.5 /Library/Tcl/tk8.5/Resources/Scripts /System/Library/Tcl/tk8.5 /System/Library/Tcl/tk8.5/Resources/Scripts /System/Library/Tcl/8.5/tk8.5 /System/Library/Tcl/8.5/tk8.5/Resources/Scripts ~/Library/Frameworks/tk8.5 ~/Library/Frameworks/tk8.5/Resources/Scripts /Library/Frameworks/tk8.5 /Library/Frameworks/tk8.5/Resources/Scripts /System/Library/Frameworks/tk8.5 /System/Library/Frameworks/tk8.5/Resources/Scripts ./library
This probably means that tk wasn't installed properly.
```

---

I'm using the latest version of R (2.14.0) on OS X 10.6.8. Seewave is 1.6.1.

Comment: Is `Tcl/tk` installed properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See http://rug.mnhn.fr/seewave/inst.html, the section about `tcl/tk` and OSX. Make sure you *also* install `tcl/tk 8.5.*`

Comment: Seems to do the trick, thanks! I installed the `pkg` provided – is there any need for a more recent version (i.e. compiling tcl/tk from source?)